# How to parse a json object in javascript

Tags: extjs, ext4

i have two JSON objects which i have to show in ExtJs grid  this is my grid and the data i am getting from Servlet i am getting a empty Grid

```
//getting the response from Servlet

 var proxy=new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:'LoginServlet'}); // this is the Servlet


var reader=new Ext.data.JsonReader( //store 

 {

 },[
     {name:'username',mapping:'username'}, //field s of Grid
     {name:'password'}//

   var store=new Ext.data.Store({  //data Store 

  proxy:proxy, //proxy
  reader:reader,//
  root:"obj" //
   });

   store.load(); //loding the store


   var grid=new Ext.grid.GridPanel({   //creating the Grid panel

   store:store,//
   columns:[

       {header:"username",width:60,dataIndex:'username'}, //setting 
       {header:"password",width:60,dataIndex:'password'}
   ],
   renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
   width:420, //
   height:200
```

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("username",UserVO.getUsername());
            obj.put("password",UserVO.getPassword());  //this is my json object

Comment: Ok, so what is the question?

Comment: i am getting an empty grid

Comment: Is the data you are sending from the server correct? Can you post some of it?

Comment: JSONObject JSONobj=new JSONObject();
            
            
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("username",UserVO.getUsername());
            obj.put("password",UserVO.getPassword());
            //out.println(obj);
            
            JSONArray json=new JSONArray();
            json.add(obj);
            JSONobj.put("obj",json);

Comment: how can i show the current time and date in ExtJs?? plz help